# Insert "NULL" as the actual text word Null using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I have a requirement to INSERT the actual word "NULL" as a text value in a SQL Server database. Is this possible? If so, how do I get that done using C#?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [IsNull()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) SQL Server function to ensure a column always returns text. That way you don't even have to deal with NULL in C# if you don't want to.

For example:

```
select isNull(TextColumn, 'NULL') as NeverNull
```

In C# you can use the following pattern to handle nulls as you desire:

```
string NeverNull = NullableVariable is null ? "NULL" : NullableVariable;
```

Comment: My apologies if I wasn't clear enough. I want to put the word "Null" INTO a field in the database, not pull it out.

Comment: No problem. Your original question didn't suggest that that was your goal. Please add the code you are currently using to insert data and we'll help you modify it to achieve your goal.

Comment: Hello, In working through this with a coworker we have identified an issue in our codebase. Thanks @EddieLotter, but nothing further is required, unless you want to see what caused the issue.

Comment: @AndrewMcFallIII, I think if your question has been answered then we can move on. I'm glad to hear your issue was resolved.